# load app component data in angular 2 after login user on other page

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have app.component which has a menu on the top. When user logged in in the login page it is redirected to the list of data page and user should see his email in the top menu but it won't loaded on ngonit in app.component. When I reload the page it is appear there.

I need it to be right after user logged in and redirected to the data list page.

app.component:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  title = 'app works!';
  userEmail: any;
  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.userEmail = this.authService.getUser().name;
    console.log(this.userEmail);
  }
}
```

login component:

```
onLogin(){
    const user ={
      email: this.email,
      password: this.password
    }

    this.authService.loginUser(user).subscribe((data)=>{
      if(data.success){
        this.authService.userData(data.token, data.user);
        this.flashMessage.show('You are logged in.', {cssClass: 'alert-success'});
        this.router.navigate(['/']);
      }else{
        console.log('user didn\'t logged in');
        this.flashMessage.show('You are not logged in. Wrong email or password.', {cssClass: 'alert-danger', timeout: 2000})
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
      }
    });

  }
```

Comment: do you have an error in the console ?

Comment: I have nothing in the console

Comment: it is like when user logged and redirected to the data list page, app.component doen't loaded but menu is there. When I reload the page user email appeared there so ngOninit works in the app.component

Comment: Try `ngAfterViewInit`. Here is a list of all [lifecycle methods](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#lifecycle-sequence).

Comment: it doesn't help

Comment: ngOnInit of AppComponent is called only once when the app is loaded.That time "this.userEmail" will be undefined (or the default value provided for "name" variable in user object from where you are fetching the name value). So nothing will be displayed in the console.

Comment: could you add the content of the AuthService ?

Comment: @Basavaraj Bhusani so how can I put useremail inside that variable and display it?

Comment: @rick1, you can create a service ("UserService"). 
This service is injected whereevr the User value is required or wherever the new user value is gotten.
In this service, Create a Subject - `let userSubject = new Subject<User>();` property i
This service can have a method which returns an observable (return "userSubject" which also acts as Observable).
or you can directly use this `userSubject` (better to use method).
Do `userSubject.next(userObject)` whenever you get user object value.
This userObject is sent to wherever it is `userSubject` is subscribed

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the user be an observable in the login service. And then have the AppComponent subscribe to the observable. Then once you login successfully, have the login method send the next observable value. The subscription in the AppComponent will be triggered and your value will be there. Does that make sense?

You can see a good example in the Angular docs. https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service

Comment: I return useremail from localstorage, like this: 
getUser(){    
      this.userEmail = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")).name;
      return this.userEmail;    
  }

Comment: how can I return observable here?

Comment: I tried them but it seems to me I failed because I do not know how to use them

Comment: Ok, let me create an example on Plunkr. I'll post it here.